# how to deal with pandas read_csv where comma is the thousand separator but characters after comma are of different length

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file, which includes the generated power for different power generation technologies. The generated power uses ,(comma) as a thousand separator, which usually is fine with the *thousands* option within ps.read_csv()

In this case the reading works for numbers which have the following structure:

1,876 converts so 1867 and 1,876.45 converts so 1876,45

meaning, that a number which has **3** numbers after the occurring comma is converted correctly.

But the given data also includes number in the following structure, which converts them incorrectly

1,23 converts so 123 but is should convert to 1230. 345,34 converts to 34534 but it should convert so 345340

Is there a way to handle those cases without manually checking the amount of numbers after the comma and adding zeros when the amount is less than 3?

For now I tried the following:

`df = pd.read_csv(path_data, sep=';', decimal='.', thousands=',')`

Comment: Could  it  be that the numbers are showing something kX, e.g. 1000*X where the 1000 separator switches to decimal separator. However this would not fit to the digits after a point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem in the pass. First I replaced the comas, where comas and points are contained in the number.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['1,27'],['1,892.25']])
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x :x.replace(',','') if '.' in x else x)
```

Than I replaced the comas with point in the numbers, where no point are contained

```
df[0] = df[0].str.replace(',','.')
```